# Similar variables are not similar

Tags: android

My searching part of code:

```
String neededShop = "not found";
float min_price=999999;
ProductHandler ph = new ProductHandler(this);
prod=ph.getAllProducts();
for(int i = 0 ; i<prod.size(); i++)
{
    if(prod.get(i).getName()==SearchProduct)
    {
        if(min_price>prod.get(i).getPrice())
        {   
            min_price=prod.get(i).getPrice();
            neededShop = prod.get(i).getShop();
        }
    }
}
```

in this part: `if(prod.get(i).getName()==SearchProduct)`

```
prod    [0] name    "Cat" (id=830032142800) 
SearchProduct   "Cat" (id=830032120832)
```

When it is comparing it returns false, in spite of they are similar. Any ideas why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String comparison is not obtained by using the **==** operator.
You get the comparison by testing **equals()**.

Try this:

```
if(prod.get(i).getName().equals(SearchProduct))
```

Comment: Hmm when i was trying equalsIgnoreCase it doesn`t work. Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't magic dude, its java... :)
double equal == are used to primitive types only
For comparing objects u need to check using equals() method

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`, for comparisson objects of `non-primitive` data type you must use [equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.